# Is there a better way to terminate the childProcess then just doing a childProcess.kill()

Tags: node.js, automation, child-process

I have a node.js server, which will print out some message in the console and then start the server.

I am creating a automation test by using tap to check the message in the console.log and check if server is started, i.e. there is a PID generated.

I tried 2 different methods -child_process.exec and child_process.spawn
1. Use child_process.exec  with a call back function. 
   This does not work as the server is long running and will not even 
   go to the call back, so I cannot even check for any stdout.

Then I use child_process.exec without call back, this solves the
   first issue where I can now get the message back from stdout.

The second issue is that the test will hang since the server is long running and will not terminate by itself.

```
 code snippet: 

 var exec = require('child_process').exec;

 tap.test('test server start', function(t) {

    childProcess= exec('node',['server']);
    console.log('[exec] childProcess.pid: ', childProcess.pid);
    t.notEqual(childProcess.pid, undefined);

    childProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('[exec] stdout: ', data.toString());
    t.match(data.toString(), "Example app listening at http://:::3000");
    t.end();
    childProcess.kill('SIGTERM');

    });
    childProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {

         console.log('[exec] stderr: ', data.toString());
    });

    childProcess.on('close', function (code) {

      if (code!=null)
         console.log('child process exited with code '+ code);
    });

    });
```

2. use child_process.spawn -code snippet

   ```
   var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
   tap.test('test server start', function(t) {

   childProcess= spawn('node',['server']);
   console.log('[spawn] childProcess.pid: ', childProcess.pid);
   t.notEqual(childProcess.pid, undefined);

   childProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log('[spawn] stdout: ', data.toString());
   t.match(data.toString(), "Example app listening at http://:::3000");
   t.end();
   childProcess.kill('SIGTERM');

   });
   childProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {

        console.log('[spawn] stderr: ', data.toString());
   });

   childProcess.on('close', function (code) {

     if (code!=null)
        console.log('child process exited with code '+ code);
   });

   });
   ```

In both 1 & 2, the test will hang since the server is long running, 
I need to use child_process.kill() to terminate the test

Is there a better method to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you can check if the server is alive in a different way (without spawning a new process).

For example, you can start your server waiting for connections:

```
const net = require('net');
var connections = {};

var server = net.createServer(function(conn) { });
server.listen(3333);

server.on('connection',function(conn) {
 var key = conn.remoteAddress + ':' + conn.remotePort;
 connections[key] = conn;
 conn.on('close',function() {
   delete connections[key];
 });
});
```

Then, connect some clients (or just one) to the server:

```
var connected = 0;
for (var i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
  var client = net.connect(3333);
  client.on('connect',function() {
    connected++;
    console.log(connected);
  });
}
```

So, if you are be able to connect to the server, then your server is alive.

And finally, when you want to close the server, just create a new function like this one:

```
var destroy = function () 
{
  server.close(function() {
    console.log('ok');
  });
  for (var key in connections) {
    connections[key].destroy();
  }
}
```

Call it for example after 10 successful connections to the server. Inside the for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var client = net.connect(3333);
  client.on('connect',function() {
    connected++;
    if (connected === 10) {
      destroy();
    }
  });
}
```

This is a very basic example, but I think that it's enough to understand another way to do what you want to do.

I.